# Extract OTP value from JSON response

Tags: json, parsing, jmeter

Following is the JSON response that I get from one of my APIs.
How do I extract the OTP 563991 in JMeter ?

```
{"status":"Success","data":{"PhoneNumber":"768909764","Body":"Please use OTP : 563991 to complete the process"},"error":null,"pagination":null,"condition":null}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) with the following expression

```
OTP(\s+):(\s+)(\d+)
```

Use Template `$3$` and Match No. `1`

You are basically ignoring spaces and getting the number after OTP

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ez1Zv2/1)